# Observable OnCompleted cannot update UI

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java

I am trying to Toast finishing a service call. However in the onComplete method I receive this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

It is thrown from `SafeSubscriber#onNext(T args)` which looks like this:

```
/**
     * Provides the Subscriber with a new item to observe.
     * <p>
     * The {@code Observable} may call this method 0 or more times.
     * <p>
     * The {@code Observable} will not call this method again after it calls either {@link #onCompleted} or
     * {@link #onError}.
     * 
     * @param args
     *          the item emitted by the Observable
     */
    @Override
    public void onNext(T args) {
        try {
            if (!done) {
                actual.onNext(args);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // we handle here instead of another method so we don't add stacks to the frame
            // which can prevent it from being able to handle StackOverflow
            Exceptions.throwIfFatal(e);
            // handle errors if the onNext implementation fails, not just if the Observable fails
            onError(e);
        }
    }
```

This is the code snippet from my code where the problem rises:

```
 NetworkService.aService()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                    .flatmap(anotherCall)
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<AddCommentResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Toast.makeText(...).show();
                    navigateBack();
                }

                // etc. ...
```

Is the problem that I cannot update UI from onCompleted method? Or where should I handle UI operations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the`anotherCall` observe on another thread. Move the `observeOn` (on the android main thread) after the `flatMap` call.

Answer (score 5):

Originally:

```
NetworkService.aService()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                    .flatmap(anotherCall)
```

After this change it is working:

```
NetworkService.aService()
                    .flatmap(anotherCall)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Answer (score 1):

NetworkService is on worker Thread. You are calling makeText(..) from the worker thread, which should be called from UI thread. Try creating a Handler and toasting from inside it.

```
ActivityContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
  public void run() { 
Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } 
});
```

Comment: So maybe shall I switch #subscribeOn() and #observeOn()? --> That doesn't work. I am just trying your suggestion. Even if it works why do I than state #observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())???

Comment: So it is working. However isn't there a better solution? I will accept the answer thank you but if somebody could provide a better answer I will accept that one.